# CsQuery - find element with concrete name

Tags: c#, csquery

I have to parse html like this:

```
<div class="navig-nav">
  <ul class="navig" id="navigmenu">
    <li class="navig-expanded navig-selected">Company</li>
    <li class="navig-sub"><div>Summary</div></li>
    <li class="navig-sub"><a href="any_url_1">Some</a></li>
    <li class="navig-sub"><a href="any_url_2">Interesting</a></li>
    <li class="navig-sub"><a href="any_url_3">Information</a></li>
    <li class="navig-item"><a href="any_url_4"><div>From</div></a></li>
    <li class="navig-item"><a href="any_url_5"><div>Web</div></a></li>
    <li class="navig-item"><a href="any_url_6"><div>Page</div></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this menu (as you can see) all classes has more than one child. How can I get "any_url_2" using csQuery if I have just the name "Interesting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
dom["a:contains('Interesting')"];
```

Well here's a more complete query:

```
CQ dom = "your html here";
var result = dom["a[href='any_url_2']:contains('Interesting')"];
if (result.Length == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result[0].Attributes["href"]);
}
```

Comment: Html could be much longer. And I have to be sure that I find exactly href "any_url_2" and not to find some text with word "Interesting" inside

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what should I do if I don't know exact url and want to find it? Just use the simple first answer?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you know and what you are looking for? In your original question you stated that you only know the string "Interesting" and you are looking for the URL of the A that contains it.

Comment: You are right! I think first simple answer is correct because it find only <a > element. So it works, Thank you very much)

Comment: What if I know exact class name? How should I do if I have to be sure that I get correct href?

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

```
dom[".navig-sub"].Find("a:contains('Interesting')")
```

a good answer?